# Minimum HW Requirements (number of machines, CPUs, RAM) for a k8ssandra and JanusGraph local cluster with Ubuntu 22.04 as common O.S.?

Tags: janusgraph, ubuntu-22.04, k8ssandra

I looked around but I didn't fine any information...

What are the Minimum HW Requirements (number of machines, CPUs, RAM) for a k8ssandra and JanusGraph local cluster with Ubuntu 22.04 as common O.S.?

Comment: Cross-posted on https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/discussions/3637

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @HadoopMarc : https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/discussions/3637

https://docs.janusgraph.org/operations/deployment/

And to this docs: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/hardware.html